# No ANSI color for rails tests, running windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot seem to get the rails tests to display in color. I am using rails version  5.0.0.rc2, running windows 10. I have installed the minitest gem, but I am getting this message:

> ansi: 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows

I did try to install win32console, this had no effect. I also noticed that win32console is deprecated, so I installed ansicon as recommended, but this did not help either. I know ansicon is working because I see colors for other actions, such as running "bundle install", yet I am still getting black and white in my tests, along with the error to install win32console. Am I missing something here? Or is this an incompatibility with the testing framework? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Here is my test_helper.rb file if that helps.

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/reporters'

Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Cmder, not plain Window's cmd.exe. However, this might work if you have the ansi gem installed or it might at least give you an idea:

Locate the file ...Ruby22\lib\gems\2.2.0\gems\ansi-1.5.0\lib\ansi\code.rb, notice near the top there is a check for the Windows platform, edit this to look something like this:

```
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /(win32|w32)/
if (ENV['ANSICON'])
  $ansi = true
else
  begin
    require 'Win32/Console/ANSI'
  rescue LoadError
    warn "ansi: 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows"
    $ansi = false
  end
end
```

You may need to change the 'ANSICON' to something similar that is in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to rails and just figuring out things so this may be a newbie reason for getting this error, but I had to put the win32console gem in my gemfiles and run bundle install. Installing gems doesn't work with rails, at least for me. Once I did that colors work fine. I am running platform 'x64_mingw' which might have something to do with it.